# Как использовать несколько классов к тексту сразу?

Tags: html

```
 <div class="text">
    <p class ="stroke"><font size="6" color="white" face="IMPACT"</font>Привет. Это мой первый сайт над которым я работал в течении 30-40 минуты</p> 
    <p class ="stroke"><font size="6" color="white" face="IMPACT"</font>пока мой приятель ходил в магазин и ехал домой.</p>
```

**Хочу применить к тексту сразу три стиля.**

```
<p class ="stroke"><p class="dline"><font size="6" color="white" face="IMPACT"</font>пока мой приятель ходил в магазин и ехал домой.</p>
```

**Вот так не работает как выше я сделал.Как указывать к тексту стили правильно?**

**Вот стили которые я хочу применить.**

```
  <style>
   .stroke {
    font: 2em Arial, sans-serif;
    text-shadow: black 1px 1px 0, black -1px -1px 0, 
                 black -1px 1px 0, black 1px -1px 0;
   }

  .text {
    text-align:  center;
   }

   p.dline {
    line-height: 1.5;
   }
   P {
    line-height: 0.9em;
   }

  </style>
```

Comment: через пробел перечисляете class="text stroke"

Comment: <p class ="класс1" "класс2" "класс3">. Так?

Comment: <p class ="класс1 класс2 класс3">.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Бладарен!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то вам надо сделать так:

```
<p class ="text dline stroke">Ваш текст</p>
```

Просто прописывайте все классы в значении атрибута `class` через пробел.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Помогли =)

Comment: @Zekoy Пожалуйста, не пишите "спасибо" в комментарии. Если ответ помог, то поставьте галочку. Ознакомьтесь со справкой https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help и сходите в тур по сайту https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour